# Return all rows query for golang rest api, using SQLX

Tags: go, sqlx

Did not find any working ways how to do this, so asking here.

How can i return json data of all of the rows in a table, using sqlx?

**Models**

```
type Author struct {
    AuthorID uint   `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"id"` // creates an aouthor_id field
    Username string `json:"name"`
}
```

I can return the username of an author, so the connection does work in this case.
**Views, using SQLX connection**

```
func TestSQLX(c *fiber.Ctx) error {

    db2, err := database.GetDbConnSqlx()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    query_author_id := `select author_id, username from authors where author_id = 2`

    var (
        author_id int
        username  string
    )

    rows, err := db2.Query(query_author_id)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        err := rows.Scan(&author_id, &username)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        log.Println(author_id, username)
    }
    err = rows.Err()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

// return err

return c.JSON(fiber.Map{
    "data": fiber.Map{
        "authors": username,
    },
})
```

}

Help appreciated.

Comment: Instead of just overwriting `author_id` and `username` every row you scan, append them to a slice.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

**Models**

```
type Author struct {
    AuthorID uint   `db:"author_id" gorm:"primaryKey" json:"id"` // creates an aouthor_id field
    Username string `db:"username" json:"name"`
}
```

**Views**

```
func TestSQLXAll(c *fiber.Ctx) error {

    db2, err := database.GetDbConnSqlx()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    query_author_all := `select * from authors;`

    authors := []models.Author{}
    db2.Select(&authors, query_author_all)

    return c.JSON(fiber.Map{
        "data": fiber.Map{
            "authors": authors,
        },
    })
}
```